# How to return HTML in javascript whilst including a variable i created?

Tags: javascript

I want to use javascript to create the following div block:

```
      <div class=id="hello">
          <h1 class="header-1"></h1>
          <img>
          <p class="paragraph-1"></p>
      </div>
```

I have another javascript object, which holds the url for the image.
It is an object with {url}. So I would like to have a function which creates the HTML code above with nesting, but also lets me assign the img src as the url of the object I have.
Do I just create a function with a return block like this:

```
 {<div class=id="hello">
          <h1 class="header-1"></h1>
          <img>
          <p class="paragraph-1"></p>
      </div>}
```

?

Comment: `<div class=id="hello">` isn't valid HTML

Comment: `const someHTML = '<p>hello <span class="foo">world !</span></p>'`

Comment: You can use [`Document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) too

Comment: @Cid this works - i had forgotten how to do it so thank you. How do I reference a js object and use is property to set the class name of the element?

Comment: You can use string concatenation

Comment: @Cid thanks a lot for your help, but i don't get quite what you mean? In your first example, suppose i want to set the div id as "hi', do I put id={'hi'}?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Cid mentioned in the comments, using `document.createElement()` is a good idea.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

</body>
<script>
  const div = document.createElement("div"); // create a div
  const h1 = document.createElement("h1"); // create a h1
  const img = document.createElement("img"); // create an image tag
  const p = document.createElement("p"); // create a paragraph

  div.classList.add("hello"); // assign "hello" css class
  div.id = "hi"
  h1.classList.add("header-1"); // assign "header" css class
  p.classList.add("paragraph-1"); // assign "paragraph-1" css class

  div.appendChild(h1); // nest h1 inside div
  div.appendChild(img); // nest img inside div
  div.appendChild(p); // nest p inside div


  document.body.appendChild(div); // add div to current document
</script>

</html>
```